# How to get the playing file total time duration Media player

Tags: asp.net, javascript, media-player

I use media player control to play mp3 files in asp.net application. I want to find When the playing process gets end and the total time require to finish the file using javascript.

Code:

```
  <object id="mediaPlayer" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
                    codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" 
                    height="1" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." 
                    type="application/x-oleobject" width="1">
                    <param name="fileName" value="" />
                    <param name="animationatStart" value="true" />
                    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true" />
                    <param name="autoStart" value="true" />
                    <param name="showControls" value="true" />
                    <param name="volume" value="100"  />
                    <param name="loop" value="true"  />
                </object>
```

Geetha.

Comment: Maybe you could show how you are *using* this media player control in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use: get_duration or get_durationString (in javascript may be "duration" or "durationString"). To see properties and methods exposed by WMP object you can download Windows Media Player SDK from Microsoft's site.